# Why would exposure settings be very different for the same scene between full-frame and APS-C (using a 10-stop ND filter)?

Tags: nikon, exposure, full-frame, cropped-sensor, neutral-density

I own a Nikon D600 and my girlfriend owns a Nikon D7000.

Recently we were out doing landscape in broad daylight with our big stoppers. We have the same 10 stop filter and we came across to something I'm not able to understand. Under the exact same circumstances, for a correct exposure I had:

1. ISO 50
2. F/11
3. 4s
4. Exposure compensation. 0

   That will give me a correct (right histogram) exposure.

For her to have the same exposure she had to do:

1. ISO 100
2. F/11
3. **30s**
4. Exposure compensation. 0

That is, she had to expose for way longer to have a proper exposure and at s bigger ISO. I though the size of the sensor wouldn't affect the quantity of light needed for an exposure but only the ISO performance.

Is this normal and a result of the sensor size? And if it is **not** normal... What could be the cause of this behaviour? What should I look at in settings of her camera or mine that justify such a difference in behaviour?

Comment: Did you have the same metering settings and did you focus on the same things? You didn't mention if the two images came out looking similar in overall exposure.

Comment: there is an f-number but there is also an T-stop. And also, of course it is possible that one was metering sky, while other wa metering land

Comment: It was landscape, we both were at around 28mm (adjusted), that is, she was at 18mm and I was at 28mm. We were both focused at infinity and the scene itself was roughly the same. It wasn't a question of metering, the actual exposure came up very differently, metering doesn't matter in this case.

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't seem normal, no. Because the f/number relates to exposure at any given point (not total sensor size), the crop factor shouldn't matter. Since you had a one-stop lower ISO, one would expect the other camera to be correct at *half* the shutter speed, not several times longer.

Were you both framing a roughly identical scene?

Does the same thing happen in *other* situations — what about without the filter?

Are you *sure* you weren't at ISO 800? The numbers would make sense then.